# can GMAIL API be used for sending out account verification when registering to a site?

Tags: api, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

can GMAIL API be used for sending out account verification when registering to a site?

I plan to use it for email registration , verification, forgot password for transactional use

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can but you may not want to unless you are using Google workspace.

To send an email using a standard google gmail account you will need to use Oauth2 and authorize the user who owns this account.   Using Gmail scopes with an Oauth2 will require your application go go though a security audit.  This audit is expensive and time consuming.  Its up to you to decide if this is worth it or not.

You could go though the SMTP server and use something called an Apps password to authorize it.  This solution would work but, google is shutting down unsave apps now and i fear that apps password will me next.  If it is your only option then would be to use Xoauth2 with smtp.  Which again may require that  you verify the app.

If you do have a google workspace account then you could set up domain wide delegation to a service account allowing it to impersonate a user on your workspace domain.  This solution would work without any issues.  It would be optimal in my opinion.